# Derived contract must override function "totalSupply". Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types

Tags: solidity, blockchain, tokens, nft, randomness

This is the code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT


pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import "https://github.com/1001-digital/erc721-extensions/contracts/RandomlyAssigned.sol";

contract VasikTest is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable, RandomlyAssigned {  
    using Address for address;

    string public uriPrefix = "";
    string public uriSuffix = ".json";
    string public hiddenMetadataUri;
    
    // Starting and stopping sale, presale and whitelist
    bool public saleActive = false;
    bool public whitelistActive = false;
    bool public presaleActive = false;
    bool public revealed = false;


    // Reserved for the team, customs, giveaways, collabs and so on.
    uint256 public reserved = 2;

    // Price of each token
    uint256 public initial_price = 0.001 ether;
    uint256 public price;

    // Maximum limit of tokens that can ever exist
    uint256 public constant MAX_SUPPLY = 10;
    uint256 public constant MAX_PRESALE_SUPPLY = 5;
    uint256 public constant MAX_MINT_PER_TX = 2;


    // Team addresses for withdrawals
    address public a1;
    address public a2;
    address public a3;

    // List of addresses that have a number of reserved tokens for whitelist
    mapping (address => uint256) public whitelistReserved;


    constructor () ERC721 ("Vasik One mint", "OneMintVasik") RandomlyAssigned(MAX_SUPPLY,1) {
        price = initial_price;
        setHiddenMetadataUri("ipfs://QmVntyJMSn8FxYVHtWig3qtfFed5aH1mr7EeXx1nespWpu/hidden.json");
    }


    function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId)
    public
    view
    virtual
    override
    returns (string memory)
  {
    require(
      _exists(_tokenId),
      "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
    );

    if (revealed == false) {
      return hiddenMetadataUri;
    }

    string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
    return bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
        ? string(abi.encodePacked(currentBaseURI, Strings.toString(_tokenId), uriSuffix))
        : "";
  }

    // See which address owns which tokens
    function tokensOfOwner(address addr) public view returns(uint256[] memory) {
        uint256 tokenCount = balanceOf(addr);
        uint256[] memory tokensId = new uint256[](tokenCount);
        for(uint256 i; i < tokenCount; i++){
            tokensId[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(addr, i);
        }
        return tokensId;
    }

    // Exclusive whitelist minting
    function mintWhitelist(uint256 _amount) public payable {
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        uint256 reservedAmt = whitelistReserved[msg.sender];
        require( whitelistActive,                   "Whitelist isn't active" );
        require( reservedAmt > 0,                   "No tokens reserved for your address" );
        require( _amount <= reservedAmt,            "Can't mint more than reserved" );
        require( supply + _amount <= MAX_SUPPLY,    "Can't mint more than max supply" );
        require( msg.value == price * _amount,      "Wrong amount of ETH sent" );
        whitelistReserved[msg.sender] = reservedAmt - _amount;
        for(uint256 i = 1; i <= _amount; i++){
            _safeMint( msg.sender, supply + i );
        }
    }

    // Presale minting
    function mintPresale(uint256 _amount) public payable {
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        require( presaleActive,                             "Sale isn't active" );
        require( _amount > 0 && _amount <= MAX_MINT_PER_TX, "Can only mint between 1 and 20 tokens at once" );
        require( supply + _amount <= MAX_PRESALE_SUPPLY,    "Can't mint more than max supply" );
        require( msg.value == price * _amount,              "Wrong amount of ETH sent" );
        for(uint256 i = 1; i <= _amount; i++){
            _safeMint( msg.sender, supply + i );
        }
    }

    // Standard mint function
    function mintToken(uint256 _amount) public payable {
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        require( saleActive,                                "Sale isn't active" );
        require( _amount > 0 && _amount <= MAX_MINT_PER_TX, "Can only mint between 1 and 10 tokens at once" );
        require( supply + _amount <= MAX_SUPPLY,            "Can't mint more than max supply" );
        require( msg.value == price * _amount,              "Wrong amount of ETH sent" );
        for(uint256 i = 1; i <= _amount; i++){
            _safeMint( msg.sender, supply + i );
        }
    }

    // Admin minting function to reserve tokens for the team, collabs, customs and giveaways
    function mintReserved(uint256 _amount) public onlyOwner {
        // Limited to a publicly set amount
        require( _amount <= reserved, "Can't reserve more than set amount" );
        reserved -= _amount;
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        for(uint256 i = 1; i <= _amount; i++){
            _safeMint( msg.sender, supply + i );
        }
    }
    
    // Edit reserved whitelist spots
    function editWhitelistReserved(address[] memory _a, uint256[] memory _amount) public onlyOwner {
        for(uint256 i; i < _a.length; i++){
            whitelistReserved[_a[i]] = _amount[i];
        }
    }

    

    // Start and stop whitelist
    function setWhitelistActive(bool val) public onlyOwner {
        whitelistActive = val;
    }

    // Start and stop presale
    function setPresaleActive(bool val) public onlyOwner {
        presaleActive = val;
    }

    // Start and stop sale
    function setSaleActive(bool val) public onlyOwner {
        saleActive = val;
    }

      function setHiddenMetadataUri(string memory _hiddenMetadataUri) public onlyOwner {
    hiddenMetadataUri = _hiddenMetadataUri;
  }

  function setUriPrefix(string memory _uriPrefix) public onlyOwner {
    uriPrefix = _uriPrefix;
  }

  function setUriSuffix(string memory _uriSuffix) public onlyOwner {
    uriSuffix = _uriSuffix;
  }

    function setRevealed(bool _state) public onlyOwner {
    revealed = _state;
    }

    // Set a different price in case ETH changes drastically
    function setPrice(uint256 newPrice) public onlyOwner {
        price = newPrice;
    }

    // Set team addresses
    function setAddresses(address[] memory _a) public onlyOwner {
        a1 = _a[0];
        a2 = _a[1];
        a3 = _a[2];
    }

    // Withdraw funds from contract for the team
    function withdrawTeam(uint256 amount) public payable onlyOwner {
        uint256 percent = amount / 100;
        require(payable(a1).send(percent * 40));
        require(payable(a2).send(percent * 40));
        require(payable(a3).send(percent * 20));
    }

    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return uriPrefix;
  }
}
```

The problem exist since i try to add the library RandomlyAssigned.sol, so i add it in the contract line `contract VasikTest is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable, RandomlyAssigned {`

And the problem that gives me is

```
  --> contracts/VasikTest.sol:11:1:
   |
11 | contract VasikTest is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable, RandomlyAssigned {  
   | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Definition in "WithLimitedSupply": 
  --> https://github.com/1001-digital/erc721-extensions/contracts/WithLimitedSupply.sol:28:5:
   |
28 |     function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Definition in "ERC721Enumerable": 
  --> https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol:45:5:
   |
45 |     function totalSupply() public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You have two functions with the same name totalSupply(). Therefore you need to either change the name of one of them, or override the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

To override the conflict you should create yet a third function with the same name right in your contract which overrides the other two.

```
function totalSupply() public view virtual override(WithLimitedSupply, ERC721Enumerable) returns (uint256) {
    return _totalSupply;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Really?! A downvote for the only response and it's correct?!!